# Rounded Borders for EditText Android

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext, styles

I am trying to create rounded borders around two of the EditTexts in my one of my layouts. For this I have created a xml **rounded_pass.xml** and assigned it as a background to **LinearLayout** containing both the EditText fields. But I also want to have a seperator between EditViews.

**rounded_pass.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <corners
                android:topLeftRadius="5dip"
                android:topRightRadius="5dip"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="5dip"
                android:bottomRightRadius="5dip"

                />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

**LoginActivity.xml:**

```
 .......
    .......
     <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_pass"
    >
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="215dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"

       />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="215dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
     />
    </LinearLayout>
    .......
    .......
```

The Effect I want to have is:
[Desired Effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qmz9u.png)

Right Now:

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTElG.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_uname"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/v1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#1caadf"></View>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you add this `android:background="@android:color/transparent"` in your `EditText`

Comment: thansk it helped me alot

Comment: You are too much awesome.

Comment: always wlc @MehvishFaisal

Answer (score 3):

Create single xml rounded_border.xml and apply it to the root layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <corners
                android:topLeftRadius="5dip"
                android:topRightRadius="5dip"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="5dip"
                android:bottomRightRadius="5dip"

                />
            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#1caadf" />
            <!--<gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="#ffffff" android:endColor="#ffffff" />-->
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of giving borders to both `Email` and `password`, give border to its parent view. i.e `RelativeLayout`, `LinearLayout` or any layout

```
<LinearLayout background="@drawable/round_corner_drawable">

    //your both edittexts

</LinearLayout>
```

Add `View` having height of `1dp` in between both your `EditText`, so that line will be drawn which will look like a border only

Comment: thank for the answer but there is a single border in between both fields as well as you can see in desired image how to deal with that.

Comment: @NiranjPatel Yes agree with you, but i thought to give correct approach to deal with that view.

Comment: @RRR you are also right, but sometime newbie get confuse with new way.

Comment: @NiranjPatel yup right, but i think newbie wants full code instead of smart solution and abhishek got benefit of that :D

Comment: @RRR agree newbie wants always a full code, I think we all earlier on at that stage also..

Answer (score 0):

There is minor changes in your shape xml file.
You have set same corner value for both file. 
There should be corner value 5 `bottomLeft` & `bottomRight` for password filed.

here is perfect code. please run in device and check it.

**rounded_uname.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="0dip"
        android:bottomRightRadius="0dip"
        android:topLeftRadius="5dip"
        android:topRightRadius="5dip"
        />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dip"
        android:color="#1caadf" />
</shape>
```

**rounded_pass.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="5dip"
        android:bottomRightRadius="5dip"
        android:topLeftRadius="0dip"
        android:topRightRadius="0dip"
        />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dip"
        android:color="#1caadf" />
</shape>
```